# Error in running python file in Sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I am trying to run a simple "hello world" program in python using sublime text 2 but when I use ctrl+B to run the program I get this error:

```
    [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    [cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\Users\\Sharan\\Documents\\lest.py']]
    [dir:  C:\Users\Sharan\Documents]
    [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP                                      SimplePass\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass\;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin]
    [Finished]
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem? I have already downloaded the latest version of python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the python executable directory to your path. It should be in `C:\Python33` (or whatever version you downloaded, hopefully 3.3). Once that's done, restart Sublime and you should be all set.